# maximum degree of generator polynomial (CRC) in CAN Bus

Tags: can-bus, crc

I am beginner in CAN and I have one question.

I have seen in documentation that generator polynomial in CRC ist (x^15 + x^14 + x^10 + x^8 + x^7 +x^4 +x^3 + x^0) and amount of Bits for CRC in CAN Bus is 15. So how does it write this polynomial into CAN Data Frame when it has only 15 Bits ? We start with x^0 and ends with x^15 means we need 16 Bits instead of 15. Or does it add automatically x^0 into generator polynomial ?

Thanks in advance

I have searched in Google, but could not find the answer

Comment: The equations of polynomials are often given with the high order bit omitted, supposedly since it is always 1 - see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) for details and sources. For example the CAN poly is expressed as 0xC599 which corresponds to the polynomial (x^15 + x^14 + x^10 + x^8 + x^7 +x^4 +x^3 + x^0) if you leave out the x^15 part. Anyway, this is all handled by hardware. The CAN controller calculates and appends the checksum at the end of each frame, and checks it on every received frame.

Comment: the 0xC599 has 16 Bits which is equal to polynomial (x^15 + x^14 + x^10 + x^8 + x^7 +x^4 +x^3 + x^0). But if we omit highest bit (which is x^15), we get 0x4599 (which has exactly 15 Bits). This will be written to CAN. Is that correct ? 
I just need to know this because I write exam ))

Comment: No, that is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

The polynomial of an *n*-bit CRC is an *n*<sup>th</sup>-degree polynomial, and so has *n+1* terms. The CRC register is *n* bits. It is the contents of the CRC register that is written, so 15 bits in this case.

When a bit is shifted out of the register, and that bit is a one, then the polynomial is subtracted (exclusive-ored) from the register and the shifted-out high bit, where the high term of the polynomial (*x<sup>n</sup>*) cancels out the bit that was shifted out. This is updates the register-plus-shifted-out-bit to be its modulus of that polynomial. That high bit is always cancelled, so it does not need to be stored, nor sent.

This is analogous to computing an integer sum modulo some number. Let's say modulo 13. Each time you add a small increment to the sum, you see if the result is 13 or more. If it is, you subtract 13.